# Extract time series according to lat/lon from a .txt

Tags: r, coordinates

A similar question to this has been answered previously, but I cannot find the solution to my particular problem:

I have a .txt with irradiance values, and I'd like to extract in a csv file a time serie of the irradiance values for a specific lat and lon.
The (head) of the .txt file looks like:

```
NCOLS 839
NROWS 679
XLLCORNER 112.025
YLLCORNER -43.975
CELLSIZE 0.05
NODATA_VALUE -999
-999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999  -999 -999 -999 -999...
```

The file hasn't a lon and lat column (this would be straightforward way to extract the data). Yet it has a header like: NCOLS, NROWS, XLLCORNER,... But I don't know how to extract a lat/long time serie with the file looking like that.

Also, once the time series for a particular lat/long is extracted, I'd like to substitute possible nodata (-999) by the average of the previous and next value of the series.

I am using an R version 3.2.4.

The downloadable link to one of the .txt files. Note this file it's for a certain year/month/day/hour. There are as much files as hours of the year.
http://www.mediafire.com/download/t7xl9adxz3764f3/solar_dni_20130102_00UT.txt

Comment: So does the text file repeat what's shown in your sample?  In other words, are there many XLL and YLL Corner values?  Since you want a time series, I assume there's dates corresponding to irradiance values...for each xll/yll corner?

Comment: @Bird. I have edited the message, please find the link to download a .txt. All .txt 8760 files of the year look the same. Accessing the file should clarify the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is an [ESRI ASCII Raster format](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm) file. Change it's name to something like `solar.asc` (the `.asc` seems to - unfortunately - be important) and then install the `SDMTools` package. Once that's done, you can do:

```
library(SDMTools)

dat <- read.asc("solar.asc")
```

or

```
df <- asc2dataframe("solar.asc")
```

It's definitely raster data (not time-series).

UPDATE

Since you need a *complete* walk-through for this.

```
library(SDMTools)

# make sure you're in the same directory as your file
getwd()

## [1] "/Path/to/the/directory/with/the/data"

# make sure your original file is in the directory
file.exists("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.txt")

## [1] TRUE

# since the SDMTools functions seem to need ".asc" at the end
file.rename("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.txt",
            "solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc")

# this reads it as a raster
dat <- read.asc("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc")

# check it out
str(dat)

##  asc [1:839, 1:679] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  - attr(*, "xll")= num 112
##  - attr(*, "yll")= num -44
##  - attr(*, "cellsize")= num 0.05
##  - attr(*, "type")= chr "numeric"


# this reads it as a data.frame
df <- asc2dataframe("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc")

## working with solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc ...

# check it out
str(dat)

##  asc [1:839, 1:679] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  - attr(*, "xll")= num 112
##  - attr(*, "yll")= num -44
##  - attr(*, "cellsize")= num 0.05
##  - attr(*, "type")= chr "numeric"

# put things back the way they were
file.rename("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc",
            "solar_dni_20130102_00UT.txt")
```

And, we can even prove this is an ESRI ASCII Raster:

```
quick.map(dat, 0.5)
```

[image]

W00t! Australia (tho the lat/long in the file already gave that away).

UPDATE #2

You can simplify the extraction by doing:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster.from.asc(dat)

as.numeric(extract(r, cbind(150.757, -26.918)))
## [1] 973
```

Comment: Thanks. But when I either change the extension to .asc or save the .txt into a plain text file wit TextEdit and change the extension to .asc: `dat <- read.asc("solar.asc")` gives the following message:
    `Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") :
  cannot open file 'solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc': No such file or directory` From there I cannot continue, any suggestion?

Comment: Thank you very much for you extended reply - I am new to R, need to catch up the logic behind. Yet I was interested in extracting the value for a specific lat, long; say lat = -26.91, long= 150.75.
I have tried something like:
   `library(SDMTools)  
    library(raster)  
    file.rename("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.txt",
                "solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc")
    df <- asc2dataframe("solar_dni_20130102_00UT.asc")
    s <- SpatialPoints(df)
    result <- extract(s, -26.918, 150.757)
    write.csv(result, "result.csv")`
But "extract" fails, would you have any idea please?

Comment: Nailed it! Many thanks! So to be sure, cbind(150.757, -26.918) assigns cbind(x, ) to lat and cbind( ,y ) to lon. And  R recognizes these x and y as lat and long because of the header of the ESRI ASCII Raster file:  XLLCORNER 112.025, YLLCORNER -43.975. Is this right?

Comment: kinda. the first two `extract()` parameters are a raster object and a matrix of points (x & y, in cols 1 & 2) to extract values from.

Comment: Why x & y should be placed in columns to be extracted from r, and not simply: extract(r,(150.757, -26.918)) ?

Comment: I usually have alot of points I'm extracting data for so I'm used to providing a matrix or a data.frame for the points.